# Cannot hold on to the screen just after the login in Xcode 9 swift 4.. protected page disappears immediately after a glimpse

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let isUserLoggedIn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isUserLoggedIn");
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    if (!isUserLoggedIn)
    {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginView", sender: self)
    }
}
```

despite using this code my `isUserLoggedIn` page disappears immediately after a glimpse after the successful login.

Comment: If I sum up your question, this is what I understood: After moving to 2nd screen from 1st screen, the 2nd screen navigates back to 1st screen immediately?

Comment: So what happens after the loginView disappears

Comment: first of all I'm new to Xcode so correct if I'm sounding technically wrong anywhere.. moving to your comment yes you are right when i enter the credentials at login page it redirects me to the next screen but just for 1 sec then it jumps back to the login page @NileshPol

Comment: it comes back to the login page where we have to enter the email and password @KarthickRamesh

Comment: can you post the code snippet from methods `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear` from your 2nd screen?

Comment: `super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
      
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let isUserLoggedIn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isUserLoggedIn");
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        
        if (!isUserLoggedIn)
        {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginView", sender: self)
        }
        
    }
}`  is this what you are asking @NileshPol

Comment: Remove the code in `viewDidAppear` from 2nd screen, it should be only on first screen. It is causing you to move back to first screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You First screen code should be:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    let isUserLoggedIn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    if !isUserLoggedIn  {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginView", sender: self)
    }
}
```

And on your second screen, the same method would be:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {}
```

You were moving to second screen from first and the same code is moving back to first screen because you had given a `segue` to both screens.